# Magical Record sorting error

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I create a bunch of Group `Entities`:

```
for (NSString *groupID in result) {
    group = [Group MR_createInContext:context];

    group.groupID = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[groupID integerValue]];
}
```

I then want to list them by a sort:

```
NSArray *groups = [Group MR_findAllSortedBy:@"groupID" ascending:TRUE inContext:context];

for (Group *group in groups) {
    DLog(@"group.groupID: %@", group.groupID);
    DLog(@"group: %@", group);
}
```

which produces the error:

```
-[__NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2595d2c0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber caseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2595d2c0'
```

My group `Entity` is auto generated:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface Group : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * groupID;

@end

@interface Group (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

@end
```

If I do the same fetch w/out Magical Record, it woks fine:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Group"];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupID" ascending:TRUE selector:nil];

NSArray *sorters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sorters];
NSError *error = nil;

NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Any ideas why I'm getting the error?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I have setup a small project with Magical Record that inserts some groups and the executes exactly your `MR_findAllSortedBy:...` fetch request and it works just fine. - Can you set a breakpoint on "All Objective-C exceptions" and post the stack backtrace where the exception happens?

Answer (score 1):

So I checked the Magical Record repo on github (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)  and I didn't see the method that you are using(probably because there was a `bug` in the documentation regarding the sorting methods for fetching the sorted entities but I saw two other methods that are recommended for fetching sorted entities.

`[entity MR_findAllSortedByProperty:@"property" ascending:YES] // single property` 
`[entity MR_findAllSortedByProperty:@"oneProperty,secondProp" ascending:YES] // mutliple properties`

Comment: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/blob/master/MagicalRecord/Categories/NSManagedObject/NSManagedObject%2BMagicalFinders.h has the method. Funny, cause I can't find the method they use in the tutorial. I wonder if that section isn't updated?

Comment: I think the tutorial was updated 20 days ago or such because there was a pull request then with those two new methods added. Are those two methods working ?

Comment: I can't find them in the classes.

Comment: Well that's rely strange :))

Comment: If you see the `findAllSortedByProperty:` method in the github repository, link to the class they are in. I do not see that method in any of them.

Comment: So I checked all the branches and there is no mention of those two methods that I added into my answer, I think there is a bug in the documentation that should be reported :)